# Prevent segue presentation in registration

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm creating a user registration form. I designed the UI interface through story board and have the sign up button action presenting the tab bar segue. I want to prevent the sign up from presenting the segue if the form validation have errors or if there was an error during registration. For some reason its not working. Any work around this???

[image]

Comment: Without any code it would be really hard for anyone to help. Please update you question with some of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender{

  if(canSignUp){
      UIViewController *viewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SignUpViewContoller"];
      [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewContoller animated:YES];
  }

}
```

Comment: I'm having trouble adding an identifier for tab bar controller. I don't see the storyboard segue identifier but I can see it for my navigation view controller

Comment: Setting the identifier for a tab bar controller should be similar as setting it for the navigation controller. Select the tab bar controller and select the third tab. It should be under the section where it asks you to set a custom class.

Comment: I just added the picture, and there is no field like the navigation controller that says Storyboard segue identifier unless you are referring to storyboard id??

Comment: Yeah the identifier for that function is the Storyboard ID

Answer (score 1):

Don't connect the segue directly to the button.  Connect it instead between the registration view controller and the post-registration destination vc.  Give it an identifier, like "ValidationPassedSegue".

Then, on the button press ...

```
- (void)registrationButtonPressed:(id)sender {

    // do validation
    if (validationPassed == YES) {
        [self performSegue:@"ValidationPassedSegue"];
```